# How to use the "breakcites" package everywhere but in one chapter

Tags: packages, citing, cite-package

I am writing my thesis with the "book" class, using the "breakcites" package.

In one chapter, it would actually be more convenient *not* to have the package. Is there a way to deactivate the package over one chapter ?

For a more complete explanation : reference labels are in 3 columns footnotes, using reledmac package. For some reasons, it happens that the last part of the label (... et al 1999) is moved to the next page's footnote. When this happens, the whole page separating the two parts of the label inherits from the \cite style (green font). I did not manage to reproduce this effect on a MWE, but I noticed that disabling the breakcites package or adding a \mbox helps, hence the question.

Best,

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!  If you cannot reproduce this effect using a MWE, then post your longer or more complicated example.  At least that way, instead of describing indirectly the problems you want solved they can be demonstrated.  I think the "minimal" in MWE is "that which demonstrates the problem using the minimum that the OP is capable of and still showing the problem" and not necessarily "brief".

Comment: +1 for the great question within the question "Is there a way to deactivate a particular package for portion of a document"?  You still should post a MWE.